# How to compare two date values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, date, compare

I have two String fields which represent Dates in my page and I would like to compare these two fields to know if my first date < second date. How can I do this?

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">First Date: </td>
    <td align="left"> <html:text name="addPublicationForm" styleId="firstDate" property="firstDate" maxlength="10"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Second Date: </td>
    <td align="left"> <html:text name="addPublicationForm" styleId="secondDate" property="secondDate" maxlength="10"/></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 62):

```
var startDt=document.getElementById("startDateId").value;
var endDt=document.getElementById("endDateId").value;

if( (new Date(startDt).getTime() > new Date(endDt).getTime()))
{
    ----------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 26):

If you are also using jQuery ui, in particular [datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker), you can use [`$.datepicker.parseDate(format, string)`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) to turn your date strings into a JavaScript `Date` object, which you can then compare using the standard `<` and `>`

Comment: Shouldn't the `Date` object returned from the code be converted into milliseconds using `Date.parse` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fparse) before making the comparison ?

Comment: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Two_digit_years_map_to_1900_-_1999

Answer (score 9):

```
var startDate = $('#start_date').val().replace(/-/g,'/');
var endDate = $('#end_date').val().replace(/-/g,'/');

if(startDate > endDate){
   // do your stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Do you know why mine is failing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015131/why-does-the-each-function-in-jquery-not-iterate

Comment: the second "-" is not replaced, try /-/g.

Comment: hello, this function will work but as stated above only one of hypen will be replaced so you can use 

var startDate = $('#start_date').val().replace('-','/').replace('-','/');
var endDate = $('#end_date').val().replace('-','/').replace('-','/');

if(startDate > endDate){
   // do your stuff here...
}

Comment: This doesn't work, don't use it. You can't compare strings like that.

Also, @Khadka you can just do a global replacement if you know how to regex. `$('#start_date').val().replace(/-/g,'/')`

Answer (score 4):

just use the jQuery datepicker UI library and convert both your strings into date format, then you can easily compare. following link might be useful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974496/jquery-javascript-convert-date-string-to-date

cheers..!!

Comment: Why is this link not linkified? It *is* valid.

Comment: because he didn't declare the hyperlink "http://"

Answer (score 2):

Once you are able to parse those strings into a [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) object comparing them is easy (Using the `<` operator). Parsing the dates will depend on the format. You may take a look at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) which might simplify this task.

Comment: i want to use the validator of jquery

Comment: +1 for 100% correct answer. @downvote, please enlighten us for what is wrong here.

Comment: @Mercer, what validato are you talking about? Are you referring to some plugin?

Comment: yes, the jquery.js and the jquery.validationEngine.js

Comment: I don't think the validator will compare two dates, will it? Won't it just validate that a date has been entered and that it is a valid date format?

Answer (score 2):

check the solution provided here it may help, i use it in my projects.
 http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ .(in the end of the page)