# jQuery validate date field for seperate year, month, date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have 3 separate fields separatly for from and two date. Year, month, Date have the `drop down lists` for the options to select. I would like to validate the form so that **To > From**. How can I implement it??

**From**

```
Year:

Month:

Date:
```

**To**

```
Year:

Month:

Date:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396526/date-now-greater-than-date-value-given
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439471/jquery-function-to-compare-date-with-current-date

Comment: @Joe - do the answers of those questions resolve your issue? Is there anything else you are after?

Comment: Kindly understand my requirement. I dont have all the fields yyyy/mm/dd in a single box. I have 3 boxes for from and 3 boxes for to (Totally 6 boxes). Each boxes have seperate ids

Answer (score 1):

You can get value from that 6 fields and arrange them shown below:

```
date_from=new Date('FROM_YEAR','FROM_MONTH','FROM_DAY');
date_from =  date_from.getTime();

date_to=new Date('TO_YEAR','TO_MONTH','TO_DAY');
date_to =  date_to.getTime();

if(date_from > date_to)
{
    alert("Please enter valid date");
    return false;
}
```