# Oracle Apex Forms

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a question about Apex Forms. I have a form with 10 fields, out of which 2 fields are "start_date" and "end_date", I want to ensure that end date must be >= start date, before the page is submitted. But the session state variables don't get user entered values until the page is submitted.

I want a way so that I can access/manipulate fields values before the page is submitted (so to reduce network traffic). Can someone please let me know how I can do it? please help.

Thanks in advance.,

Comment: Could you help more by clarifying the process flow of the use case you presented?  What fields are optional?  What does a `SUBMIT` event signify?  At what point is the user going back to revise or add to their data from the original input?  Where does the data go after `SUBMIT` is reached?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check the form without submitting it is via Javascript. You could have a button that calls a Javascript function to check the data before submitting the form.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004178/how-to-compare-two-date-values-with-jquery) for some guidance on comparing dates in Javascript.

If you are not experienced with Javascript then this will be quite tricky!  Are you sure it is necessary?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I know Javascript up to some extent. Can you tell how to call a Javascript function from within APEX Page? I will also look at the link you provided. Thanks again.

Comment: One way is to create an APEX button that redirects to a URL and make the URL like `javascript:my_function();`.  Then create the definition of `my_function` in the Javascript section of the page attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation components for those kind of things: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/bldr_validate.htm

Comment: Validations are processed when the page is submitted though.

Comment: Those validations occur only after page is submitted. I am talking about checking values before page is submitted. Thanks.

Comment: then do what @TonyAndrews suggests. Just check those values with javascript.