# Setting TextBox.Text after Selecting a Date on an Ajax CalendarExtender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, calendarextender

On an ASP.NET page, I have a pair of `CalendarExtender` (AJAX Control Toolkit for ASP.NET 4.0) controls on a page acting as a date range. What I want to do is, after the user has selected the value for `TextCheckInDate` , populate `TextCheckOutDate` with `TextCheckInDate+ 1` if `TextCheckOutDate` is empty.

Regrettably, my jQuery skills aren't yet where I'd like them to be. I know that I have to create a jQuery function that's fired when `TextCheckInDate` changes, I need to be able to read both textboxes, perform basic date arithmetic and write to the second textbox. The implementation eludes me. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974496/jquery-javascript-convert-date-string-to-date), I know to use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) for my date arithmetic, included below...

What I have so far:

```
$("input[id$='TextCheckInDate']").keyup
    (function (e) {
        checkCheckOutDate( $("#TextCheckInDate").val() );
    }
    );


function checkCheckOutDate(checkInDate) {
    var startDate = Date.parse(checkInDate);
    if ($("#TextCheckOutDate").val() == "") {
        $("#TextCheckOutDate").val((1).days().after(startDate));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you prohibit to enter text into date textboxes? If so, you can use following approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkInDateChanged(sender, args) {
        var checkInDate = sender.get_selectedDate();

        var checkOutDateExtender = $find("CheckOutdateExtender");
        var checkOutdate = checkOutDateExtender.get_selectedDate();
        if (checkOutdate == null || checkOutdate < checkInDate) {
            checkOutdate = new Date(checkInDate.setDate(checkInDate.getDate() + 1));
            checkOutDateExtender.set_selectedDate(checkOutdate);
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextCheckInDate" />
<ajax:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="CheckInDateCalendarExtender" TargetControlID="TextCheckInDate"
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkInDateChanged" />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextCheckOutDate" />
<ajax:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="CheckOutDateCalendarExtender" BehaviorID="CheckOutdateExtender"
    TargetControlID="TextCheckOutDate" />
```

in PreRender method add code below:

```
TextCheckInDate.Attributes.Add("readOnly", "readonly");
TextCheckOutDate.Attributes.Add("readOnly", "readonly");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to tweak your code slightly to also fire your `checkCheckOutDate()` function when the checkin textbox's `change` event fires.

```
$("input[id$='TextCheckInDate']").bind('keyup,change', function (e) {
    checkCheckOutDate( $("#TextCheckInDate").val() );
});


function checkCheckOutDate(checkInDate) {
    var startDate = Date.parse(checkInDate);
    if ($("#TextCheckOutDate").val() == "") {
        $("#TextCheckOutDate").val((1).days().after(startDate));
    }
}
```

Note that lots of the event methods in jQuery like `click()`, `keyup()`, etc are just wrappers around `bind('click', function() { ... })`.