# How to add or subtract dates in C# using ajax calendar extender?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-3.0

I have two textboxes in which I have used ajax calendar extender. When I choose a date from one of the text boxes, it should automatically fill the other textbox by adding some days or months.

How can I do that?

Comment: guys help me please i am a begginer on c#...

Comment: Please post some code showing what you currently have implemented.

Comment: Umar you need to google DateTime in .NET and then use DateTime.Add Methods. you can add days, year , month etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6275899/360171

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this example and modify your code. Hope it helps.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<contenttemplate>
<cc2:CalendarPopup id="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Width="71px" OnDateChanged="CalendarPopup1_DateChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></cc2:CalendarPopup>
<cc2:CalendarPopup id="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" Width="71px"></cc2:CalendarPopup>
</contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>        

**Code behind:**

 protected void CalendarPopup1_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarPopup2.SelectedDate = CalendarPopup1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1); // you can add the number of days you want
    }
```

Also the following link might give you better insight on this topic:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=149