# Formatting Time Django Template

Tags: python, django, timezone, timestamp

I am extracting a time stamp from JSON which I want to convert to EST and format in human readable form.

When I extract it from JSON, I get the following text: "2012-06-30T10:36:06-07:00"

How do I convert it to east coast time (+3 hours) and in proper format ("6-30-2012 1:36pm")?

Comment: Other answers that might help - in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime and in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974496/jquery-javascript-convert-date-string-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [pyiso8601](http://code.google.com/p/pyiso8601/) package that does this exactly. It accepts `tzinfo` which you can use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library to get predefined timezones. [they have plenty of e.g.]